# Firefox Sandbox import function from namespace?

Tags: javascript, firefox, namespaces, sandbox

I'd like to execute a set of function from a namespace in a sandbox inside the plugin I'm currently developing, I've done something like that:

```
if (typeof namespace == "undefined") {

      var namespace = {     
        foo:function(){return 0},

        goo:function(){
          var s = new Components.utils.Sandbox("http://code.google.com/p/headertool/");
          //importing utility method inside the sandbox
          s.importFunction(namespace.foo);                //FAIL...
          var result = Components.utils.evalInSandbox(code, s);
          return result;
        }
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
 (function() {

   this.startup();
  }).apply(namespace);


}
```

but when I try to import the function I got this error :

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal value"  nsresult: "0x80070057 
(NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://headertool/content
/overlay.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 321"  data: no]
```

I think this is related because the function I'm trying to import isn't in the current contex, there is a better solution for or the only way to resolve the problem is make function public in the main context like:

```
if (typeof namespace == "undefined") {

      var namespace = {     

        goo:function(){
          var s = new Components.utils.Sandbox("http://code.google.com/p/headertool/");
          //importing utility method inside the sandbox
          s.importFunction(namespace.foo);                //OK...
          var result = Components.utils.evalInSandbox(code, s);
          return result;
        }
/**
 * Constructor.
 */
 (function() {

   this.startup();
  }  ).apply(namespace);

};

//Global namespace
function foo(){return 0};
```

Comment: you need to do 

`var s = new Components.utils.Sandbox("http://code.google.com/p/headertool/");
s.funct=mynamespace.private_funct`